# Updating balance factor in AVL tree after rotation - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

I am working on implementing an AVL tree in c++, and am familiar with the concepts of single and double rotation. I have implemented the tree successfully by calculating `balance_factor = height(left_child) - height(right_child)`, and **trying to implement a more efficient AVL tree by storing its balance factor and keeping it within the range of [-1, 1]**. Note that I am currently looking only at insertion, before attempting to delete based off balance factors.

In essence, the pseudo-code for inserting is as follows:

1. Find the right place to insert the node, pushing each node accessed into a stack starting from the root node
2. Update balance factors of all nodes in the stack one at a time, but stopping if the balance factor is adjusted to 0 in the process.
3. Using the stack, recursively balance the tree at whichever node that holds a `balance_factor` of -2 or 2.

So far, it appears that this algorithm more or less works with some sets of values, **but fail to work in some situations.**

[Inserting values 0 to 9 randomly (balance factors are correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv9Ae.png)

[Inserting string values randomly (root node balance factor is incorrect after LR rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwqrk.png)

Looking the AVL tree of strings, my algorithm stops propagating once it reaches a node that has its `balance_factor` updated to 0. In the bottom case, the updating of balance factors stops at `one[0]`, and the balance factor of the root node `fad[-1]` is not updated to 0 although its subtrees share the same maximum height.

The wiki page on AVL trees mention that:

> The retracing can stop if the balance factor becomes 0 implying that the height of that subtree remains unchanged.

However, I am unable to see why this is the case when a LR/RL rotation potentially requires propagating the update of `balance_factor` values beyond such a node.

***TL;DR: Am I doing something conceptually wrong?***

**Insertion**

```
template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::insert(const T& value)
{
    std::stack<BinTree> path_nodes;
    insert_in_node(BSTree<T>::get_root(), value, path_nodes);
}

template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::insert_in_node(BinTree& node, const T& value,
    std::stack<BinTree>& path_nodes)
{
    if (!node)
    {
        node = BSTree<T>::make_node(value);
        update_balance_factors(path_nodes, value, true);
        balance(path_nodes);
    }
    else
    {
        ++node->count;
        path_nodes.push(node);

        if (value < node->data)
            insert_in_node(node->left, value, path_nodes);
        else if (value > node->data)
            insert_in_node(node->right, value, path_nodes);
    }
}
```

**Balancing/Updating balance factor values**

```
template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::balance(std::stack<BinTree>& path_nodes)
{
    while (!path_nodes.empty())
    {
        BinTree tree = path_nodes.top();
        path_nodes.pop();

        int balanceFactor = tree->balance_factor;

        if (balanceFactor < -1 || balanceFactor > 1)
        {
            // there is a need to rotate and balance
            if (balanceFactor > 0)
            {
                // left side is deeper than right side
                if (tree->left->balance_factor > 0)
                {
                    // LL
                    rotate_right(tree);
                }
                else
                {
                    // LR
                    rotate_left(tree->left);
                    rotate_right(tree);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // right side is deeper than left side
                if (tree->right->balance_factor < 0)
                {
                    // RR
                    rotate_left(tree);
                }
                else
                {
                    // RL
                    rotate_right(tree->right);
                    rotate_left(tree);
                }
            }

            reparent(path_nodes, tree);
            update_balance_factors(path_nodes, tree->data, false);
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::update_balance_factors(std::stack<BinTree> path_nodes,
    const T& value, bool inserting)
{
    while (!path_nodes.empty())
    {
        BinTree parent = path_nodes.top();
        path_nodes.pop();

        if (value < parent->data)
        {
            // value belongs to the left subtree
            if (inserting)
                ++parent->balance_factor;
            else
                --parent->balance_factor;
        }
        else
        {
            // value belongs to the right subtree
            if (inserting)
                --parent->balance_factor;
            else
                ++parent->balance_factor;
        }

        // break out of loop if balance factor is adjusted to 0
        if (!parent->balance_factor)
            break;
    }
}
```

**Rotations/Reparenting**

```
template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::rotate_left(BinTree& pivot)
{
    BinTree temp = pivot;
    pivot = pivot->right;
    temp->right = pivot->left;
    pivot->left = temp;

    temp->count -= ((pivot->right) ? pivot->right->count : 0) + 1;
    pivot->count += ((temp->left) ? temp->left->count : 0) + 1;

    temp->balance_factor += 1
        - ((pivot->balance_factor < 0) ? pivot->balance_factor : 0);

    pivot->balance_factor += 1
        + ((0 < temp->balance_factor) ? temp->balance_factor : 0);
}

template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::rotate_right(BinTree& pivot)
{
    BinTree temp = pivot;
    pivot = pivot->left;
    temp->left = pivot->right;
    pivot->right = temp;

    temp->count -= ((pivot->left) ? pivot->left->count : 0) + 1;
    pivot->count += ((temp->right) ? temp->right->count : 0) + 1;

    temp->balance_factor -= 1
        + ((pivot->balance_factor > 0) ? pivot->balance_factor : 0);

    pivot->balance_factor -= 1
        - ((0 > temp->balance_factor) ? temp->balance_factor : 0);
}

template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::reparent(std::stack<BinTree>& path_nodes,
    const BinTree& orphan)
{
    if (path_nodes.empty())
    {
        BSTree<T>::get_root() = orphan;
    }
    else
    {
        BinTree parent = path_nodes.top();
        if (parent->data < orphan->data)
            parent->right = orphan;
        else
            parent->left = orphan;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!